# how to setup url friendly in yii framework automatically 

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I just learning yii framework and read this tutorial 
about [yii how to setup url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/topics.url)

but I have no idea, suppose i have 10 controllers, should I define one by one controllers in the config file ? 
is there a better way to setup url friendly like www.yoursite.com/yourController/yourAction/yourID for all controller ?

I think codeigniter did that automatically ... how about yii ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In /protected/config/main.php add..

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,      
        ),
    ),
```

In your web root an .htaccess..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: I wish I could give +10 votes for this answer, as finding it would have saved me an hour of searching and struggling to get it to work properly.

Comment: I followed as your answer. but I think I've no luck. I uncomment the urlManager when I generate a app with yii at [app root]/protected/config/main.php . And I add your .htaccess into my [app root]/.htaccess. but I got the 404 error. pls help me to solve.

Comment: @tharsoe I was getting the 404 error and my .htaccess file wasn't in root but inside the protected folder. I moved it up to root. (same location as index.php) and it started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are automatical URL generation in Yii too. For example just write in your template such URL **without** manual route:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('topic title',array('topic/view','id'=>$topic->id,'var'=>'123')); ?>
```

And rendered URL will be as follow:

```
/topic/view/id/1/var/123
```

Then in our action actionView() method we use these parameters:

```
...
$id=$_GET['id'];
$var=$_GET['var'];
...
```