# YiiBoilerplate Url Rewriting - php yii

Tags: mod-rewrite, yii

When we configure YiiBoilerplate. we use its frontend by these url

```
http://localhost/YiiBoilerplate-master/frontend/www/index.php/site/
```

i want to change this url and access it like 
`http://localhost/YiiBoilerplate-master/site/index.`
how it is possible by `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: This question doesn't match to the [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189823/how-to-setup-url-friendly-in-yii-framework-automatically) because it is using yii boilerplate which has different url then the url mentioned in this question.

Comment: https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

Add a `.htaccess` file to your webserver root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/YiiBoilerplate-master/(.*) /YiiBoilerplate-master/frontend/www/index.php/$1
```

This gives you access to your app via a shorter URL, but the links within the app still stay in the longer form. To update the URLs within your app, update `baseUrl` in the `urlManager` component:

```
'components' =>
    'urlManager' => array(
        'baseUrl' => '/YiiBoilerplate-master',
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        ...
```

**Note: I'd strongly recommend setting up a virtual host.**

Comment: Do you just want to access it via this URL or should all URLs created in the application also follow this format?

Comment: I think  virtual host is not good option because i regularly upload on live server.

Comment: Check your logs for the 500 error, maybe just a typo or missing apache module.

The virtual host is intended to minimize differences between your development system and live system, you can run both sites with the same relative paths.

Comment: i have recovered 500 error but your suggestion is not solving my problem. normally backend works with this url: `http://localhost:85/yii-bilerplate/backend/www/index.php` and i want my application accessible just with this url `http://localhost:85/yii-bilerplate/`. it should open the backend.

Comment: thank you for taking interest in this problem's solution @schmunk

Comment: So, just to clarify this, you want the frontend part accessible via port 80 and the backend via port 85?

Comment: i am not using any other port except 85

Comment: OK, did you try to add a .htaccess file into your **webserver root**, so that you can at least enter `http://localhost:85/yii-bilerplate/` into your browser and see your application?

Comment: yeah! i have tried yours and a lot more suggestions except virtual host.

Comment: Then only the internal links are still pointing to the long URL, have you tried updating the `urlManager` `baseUrl` property? Which errors do you still have?

Comment: in `baseUrl` first i had put only `/yii-bilerplate` now i have change it with `http://localhost:85/yii-bilerplate/`. in result there is no `frontend/www` in url but raising `error404`. When i click on About page it redirects to a url `http://localhost:85/yii-bilerplate/site/about` and shows `404`.

Comment: Hmm, I've added `urlFormat` to the answer, if that doesn't help it seems, that I am at my wit's end.

Comment: `'urlFormat'=>'path'` is already there. using yiiboilerplate first time..  Anyway thanks for your time and interest. :)