# Yii URL configuration

Tags: php, yii

I am creating an yii application and i made some changes to it :

I created a default folder and admin folder and i put all folders(MVC) in side each one and i  redirected all unknown request like :
127.0.0.1/myframework to 127.0.0.1/myframework/default with .htaccess and it work just fine.

It works when i go to default page but when i want to go deeper to another controller like 127.0.0.1/myframework/default/contactus it return not found (I made MVC for contactus) so i was thinking i should make changes to main.php in 'urlManager' section but i don't know how and all my efforts fails . so any help would be appreciated .

my structure is like:

> root
>
> ```
> admin
>
>     asset
>
>     protected
>
>     ...
>
> default
>
>     asset
>
>     protected
>
>     ...
> ```

Comment: Post the code you tried in the urlManager.

Comment: I tried 'default/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'default/<controller>/<action>', but no success and i know it is wrong.

Comment: Try `'default/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'`

Comment: I tried it Sir, nothing changed.

Comment: I don't understand your file structure, not sure why you have all files twice. You should use permissions not have two seperate directories with all files duplicated. Do you have two seperate config folders with main.php?

Comment: Yes they have separate config file ,nothing duplicated i just separated back end from front end.

Comment: Right you should only have one config file. You can separate using the urlManager, you don't actually have to have separate folders.

Comment: Yes i don't have to separate folder but i want to ,there is no way i can do this by separate folders ? this should work like two separate application.

Comment: Similar question, maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14933912/291573

Comment: You are going to have to depend on .htaccess to send the correct request to the correct index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guy's for your comments they lead me to the solution and the solution is :

First - the complete URL is something like :

> 127.0.0.1/myframework/default/index.php/services

works just fin with my previous configuration , i just missed typing index.php , without any configuration in main.php with "urlManager" section , pretty obvious , i know .

For getting ride of annoying  "index.php" in URL , .htaccess do the magic .

So i put two .htaccess in my project one in the root other in the default folder.

Root htaccess contain :

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^$ http://[local-host]/myframework/default/index.php

and default folder htaccess:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
>   !-d
>
> RewriteRule . index.php