# Change module url in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have the following url
 http://localhost.com/projectname/index.php?r=site/cms&view=about_us
I want to change this url as following
  http://localhost.com/projectname/about_us,
using htaccess and urlmanager then what have to to do?

Comment: This question has been answered before, check this:

[how to setup url friendly in yii framework automatically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189823/how-to-setup-url-friendly-in-yii-framework-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **Priya jain** has already given an answer to you about hiding the index.php from your Url. In order to change your Url to  http://localhost.com/projectname/about_us you can make the following change in your **config/main.php**

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                              // add this line
                                '<view:\w+>'=>'site/cms',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

If still you are unable to **hide index.php** then you can try this

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on the engine:
RewriteEngine on
# Don't perform redirects for files and directories that exist:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# For everything else, redirect to index.php:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</ifModule>
```

**Note:-** Save it as **your project/.htaccess** and remember the **showScriptName** should be **false** in your `urlManger array() in config/main.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try This code index.php part in the url gets removed and works fine :

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

create .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

if not works try

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

dont forget to uncomment urlmanager in protected/config/main.php file

Answer (score 0):

in yii 
first you should edit main/config.php like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'showScriptName' => false,
                        'rules'=>array(
                            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                        ),
                    ),
```

(this step can help you hide index.php)

and second , create a .htaccess file in document ,print this:

Options +FollowSymLinks
    IndexIgnore */*
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

PS： this is my config,it help your url look clear:

```
'rules'     => array(
        '/login'                => 'user/account/login',
        '/logout'               => 'user/account/logout',
        '/registration'         => 'user/account/registration',
),
```